# PHP rebuild configure options

Tags: php, makefile, installation, configure

I built PHP in RHEL a while ago using the infamous configure/make/make install procedure, instead of using yum. Now, I planned to include SNMP in my PHP build, but I couldn't find the old configure command. Now I have to reconstruct the configure command just to include the SNMP component. While doing so, I had a thought if there's a way to automatically regenerate the configure command with all the options and parameters. I searched high and low in Google, but I can't find any. So I post here to ask if such method exists. Please share if such step is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind the question, I find it out already. For those interested to know, just run phpinfo() and from web browser, you'll find the configure command.